# When should we use two-dimensional pointer in objective c

Tags: objective-c, pointers, runtime

I want to know when should we use two-dimensional pointer in objective c. I read a article about the runtime mechanism. The implementation details of method objc_msgSend is as follows:

1. Any `NSObject` objective has a attribute of `isa` which will point to the corresponding `Class` object.

   ```
   @interface NSObject <NSObject> {
       Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;
   }
   ```
2. `Class` objective is as follows:

   ```
   struct objc_class {
       Class isa;  

       Class superclass;   
       const char *name;   
       uint32_t version;   
       uint32_t info;        
       uint32_t instance_size;         
       struct old_ivar_list *ivars;    
       struct old_method_list **methodLists;    // Method list of the class
       Cache cache;    
       struct old_protocol_list *protocols;   
   }
   ```

   The question I want to ask is that why methodLists is two-dimensional pointer, what if we use one-dimensional or do not use pointer, can sb explain this question to me?Thanks in advance.

   The struct old_method_list is as below:

   ```
    struct old_method_list {
    void *obsolete;         
    int method_count;     
    /* variable length structure */
    struct old_method method_list[1];   //The address of the first Method   
    };
   ```

   OK, I read another article about why old_method_list use two-dimensional pointer, the reason is that, it may point to an array.My another question is that for `struct old_method method_list[1]`, the comment is "The address of the first Method", but method_list is an old_method array which length is 1. How it can store address?

I solved this question by reading another article.
The array struct old_method method_list[1] is dynamic, it can be changed by adding elements(methods) to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it points at array of pointers at `old_method_list`.

Update for `old_method_list`.

`old_method_list *` can point not just at `old_method_list`. It also can point at for example:

```
struct old_method_list_with_10_methods
{
 struct old_method_list list;
 struct old_method method_list[9];
};
```

Or if you need dynamic size:

```
old_method_list* list = malloc(sizeof(old_method_list) + (n-1) * sizeof(old_method));
list->method_count = n;
```

It's such variable length structure.

Comment: my another question is that for struct old_method method_list[1], the comment is "The address of the first Method", but method_list is an old_method array which length is 1. How it can store address?

Comment: @Jay, it doesn't store array's address it's first element of array. You just allocate more bytes if you need more items. You can freely use `method_list[1]`, `method_list[2]`, etc., if you have allocated enough bytes. I have already provided code how create old_method_list for `n` elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help